# PhpStorm debug makes scripts run faster than without debug enabled?

Tags: php, performance, apache, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I usually expect that an IDE in debug mode would increase load and decrease performance of the application you are debugging.

However, it seems that with PhpStorm "something" happens, which increases the end performance. I've been trying to narrow down the cause, but I failed. So hence, my first SO question.

Old run - with PhpStorm. New run - without PhpStorm debug enabled.

[image]

Does anyone here know what's going on?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "PhpStorm debug enabled"? What are those numbers on a chart even mean (more is better or other way around)?.

Comment: I assume you are talking about Xdebug debugging. When you have Xdebug setup to debug every single request (start with request) .. or on trigger (when Xdebug sees "debug me" cookie/param in request) then it tries to connect to debug client (PhpStorm in your case). before it was about 1sec delay, now it's about 0.2sec (200ms). If PhpStorm is listening, then session is getting established .. and f you have no breakpoints then it may just run all the way through without stopping.

Comment: If PhpStorm is not listening for incoming debug connections (or on the wrong port etc) then Xdebug still waits that 200ms till it will continue with execution "no debug client present so run without debugging session". That 200ms may make the difference. In either case: just having Xdebug enabled may make your execution time 2x slower (mainly for Xdebug v2; new v3 offers more control over what functions will be enabled based on `xdebug.mode` value)

Comment: P.S. For CLI scripts, if launched from PhpStorm, IDE allows to load Xdebug extension for "Debug" action only (by passing additional params to the PHP executable) and will run normal on "Run" (assuming that you do not have Xdebug extension enabled in your php.ini). Obviously, this does not affect Apache/nginx/IIS/etc as in such case the actual web server controls how PHP is run.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the detailed answers! I think that your second comment is actually the answer - I will check this and reply to you.

Lots of good details in your comments - I much appreciate your time taken to answer!